# MVC 3 Rendering a section in a area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I am trying to render a section that is defined in _layout file from my custom area.

In my area I have the _ViewStart which points to the _layout in the root site.

The section that I am trying to use is in the head tag, but in my area it is put in the body.

Page that are rendered at the root level work fine.

~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

```
<head>

    @RenderSection("header", true)
</head>
<body>
 ....
</body>
```

~/Areas/UserMedia/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

~/Areas/UserMedia/Views/ManageProjectMedia.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ManageProjectMedia";
}

@section header{
{
<!-- scripts and styles -->
}

<div>
 ... page content
</div>
```

Comment: Any code you can provide would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your question you pointed out a code sample whose path is `~/Views/_layout.cshtml` and on your _ViewStart.cshtml file under your area, you have the following code :

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

<strike>I am sure you will find the seven difference here :)</strike>

Seven difference thing was a joke but anyway. Your `_Layout.cshtml` is sitting under `~/Views/` but you're referencing `_Layout.cshtml` which is under `~/Views/Shared/`.

Comment: seven difference?

If you mean _layout.cshtml and _Layout.cshtml, I missed typed that when I updated the question.